# Rewriting a code for better and faster performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a big issue with the following code and needs help. This is 1 of 6 of my main headache for weeks.
When i run the following code for a client with 20GB Database, it takes so many hours to complete.
I now the code is poorly written and i need help to get it fixed, please.

Code is as follows :

```
Set rstCount = MyConn.Execute("Select count(*) as CNT from tblLoanTable1")
Set rst = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblLoanTable1 where Acctno <> '' order by AcctNo")
If rst.BOF Then
Else

PBar.Max = Val(rstCount!CNT) + 1
PBar.Value = 0
Do Until rst.EOF

ODCAUGHT = False

''CHECK IF THE LOAN IS PERFORMING

Set rst1 = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblOverdraftTable1 where acctno = '" & rst!acctno & "' and expirydate >= '" & Date & "'  ")
If rst1.BOF Then
Else

If Val(rst1!OBal) >= Val(rst!NonVal) Then
   GoTo BADA
Else
   ODCAUGHT = True
   A4 = Round(Val(rst!NonVal) - Val(rst1!OBal), 2)
End If

End If

CONST4 = "NON PERFORMING OVERDRAFTS"

If Option3.Value = True Then
GD = rst!EntryDate
ElseIf Option4.Value = True Then
GD = rst!TransDate
Else
End If

STDate = GD
A2 = dtDate1.Value - GD

If Val(A2) < 0 Then
   GoTo BADA
End If



If MCLASS = False Then

If Val(A2) >= 0 And Val(A2) <= 30 Then
   CONST = "CATEGORY1"
   CD1 = 0.05
   CD3 = 0.05
ElseIf Val(A2) > 30 And Val(A2) <= 90 Then
   CONST = "CATEGORY2"
   CD1 = 0.2
   CD3 = 0.2
ElseIf Val(A2) > 90 And Val(A2) <= 180 Then
   CONST = "CATEGORY3"
   CD1 = 0.5
   CD3 = 0.5
ElseIf Val(A2) > 180 Then
   CONST = "CATEGORY4"
   CD1 = 1
   CD3 = 1
Else
   GoTo BADA
End If

End If



A3 = Round(Val(rst!NonVal), 2)

If Val(A2) = 1 Then
A6 = Val(A2) & " Day"
Else
A6 = Val(A2) & " Days"
End If

If ODCAUGHT = True Then
A3 = Val(A4)
Else
A3 = Round(Val(rst!NonVal), 2)
End If

AB1 = ""
AB2 = ""
AB3 = ""
AB4 = ""
AB5 = "OVERDRAFT"

Set rst6 = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblCustomersTable1 where acctno = '" & rst!acctno & "'")
If rst6.BOF Then
Else
CustBal1 = Round(Val(rst6!Balance), 2)
CustBlock = rst6!Blocked
AB1 = rst6!AcctD
AB2 = rst6!AcctO
AB3 = rst6!Ccode
AB4 = BranchName(rst6!Ccode)
AB5 = "OVERDRAFT"
end if

CD4 = Round(Val(CD3) * Val(A3), 2)
BAL1 = Val(CustBal1)


If CustBlock = "Y" Then
GoTo OGD
End If

ValB = Round(-1 * Val(BAL1), 2)
Bal = Val(Mafi6)
BAL2 = Round((ValB * Bal) / 36500, 2)

OGD:
Sno = Val(Sno) + 1



'CHECK EXPIRY DATE

Set rst5 = MyConn.Execute("Select * from tblLoanRecord2 where AccountID = '" & rst!acctno & "' and Finish = 'Y'")
If rst5.BOF Then
ExpDate = dtDate1.Value
GoTo MOVEON
Else

Set rst9 = MyConn.Execute("Select Max(Loandate) as Loandate from tblLoanRecord2 where AccountID = '" & rst!acctno & "' and Finish = 'Y'")
If rst9.BOF Then
ExpDate = dtDate1.Value
GoTo MOVEON
Else

Set Rst10 = MyConn.Execute("Select * from tblLoanRecord2 where AccountID = '" & rst!acctno & "' and Loandate = '" & rst9!Loandate & "' and Finish = 'Y'")
If Rst10.BOF Then
Else

RepMETHOD = Rst10!Paymentopt

If RepMETHOD = "Daily" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + Val(Rst10!duration)
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Weekly" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + (7 * Val(Rst10!duration))
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Monthly" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + (30 * Val(Rst10!duration))
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Semi - Monthly" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + (15 * Val(Rst10!duration))
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Quarterly" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + (90 * Val(Rst10!duration))
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Bi - Annually" Then
   ExpDate = Rst10!Loandate + (180 * Val(Rst10!duration))
End If
End If
End If
End If

MOVEON:

If STDate > ExpDate Then
   ExpDate = STDate + 30
End If

If CONST = "CATEGORY1" Then
MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!acctno & "','" & Replace(rst!ACCTName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & "','" & 

Replace(rst!AcctO, "'", "''") & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & A6 & "','N/A','N/A','" & rst!TType & "','" & STDate 

& "','" & ExpDate & "','OVERDRAFT','" & CONST4 & "','0','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(A3) & "','0','0','0','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) & "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" 

& CONST & "','" & AB1 & "','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")
ElseIf CONST = "CATEGORY2" Then
MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!acctno & "','" & Replace(rst!ACCTName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & "','" & 

Replace(rst!AcctO, "'", "''") & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & A6 & "','N/A','N/A','" & rst!TType & "','" & STDate 

& "','" & ExpDate & "','OVERDRAFT','" & CONST4 & "','0','" & Val(A3) & "','0','" & Val(A3) & "','0','0','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) & "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" 

& CONST & "','" & AB1 & "','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")
ElseIf CONST = "CATEGORY3" Then
MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!acctno & "','" & Replace(rst!ACCTName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & "','" & 

Replace(rst!AcctO, "'", "''") & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & A6 & "','N/A','N/A','" & rst!TType & "','" & STDate 

& "','" & ExpDate & "','OVERDRAFT','" & CONST4 & "','0','" & Val(A3) & "','0','0','" & Val(A3) & "','0','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) & "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" 

& CONST & "','" & AB1 & "','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")
ElseIf CONST = "CATEGORY4" Then
MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!acctno & "','" & Replace(rst!ACCTName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & "','" & 

Replace(rst!AcctO, "'", "''") & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & Val(BAL2) & "','" & A6 & "','N/A','N/A','" & rst!TType & "','" & STDate 

& "','" & ExpDate & "','OVERDRAFT','" & CONST4 & "','0','" & Val(A3) & "','0','0','0','" & Val(A3) & "','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) & "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" 

& CONST & "','" & AB1 & "','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")
Else
End If

If ODCAUGHT = True Then
   MyConn.Execute ("Update tblLoanTable1Temp set NonVal = '" & Val(A3) & "' where AcctNo = '" & rst!acctno & "' and RefNo2 = '" & rst!RefNo2 & "'")
End If

BADA:
PBar.Value = PBar.Value + 1
rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If

PBar.Value = Val(rstCount!CNT) + 1



'PART TWO 

Set rstCount = MyConn.Execute("Select count(*) as CNT from tblLoanTable10")
Set rst = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblLoanTable10  order by accountid")
If rst.BOF Then
Else

PBar.Max = Val(rstCount!CNT) + 1
PBar.Value = 0
Do Until rst.EOF
Set rst1 = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblLoanRecord2 where accountid = '" & rst!AccountID & "' and RefNo = '" & rst!RefNo & "'")
If rst1.BOF Then
   GoTo BADA2
Else
   RepMETHOD = rst1!Paymentopt
   CONST = Val(rst1!duration) * 30
   DD1 = rst!Loandate + Val(CONST)
   DD2 = rst!deductdate
   CONST2 = Round(Val(rst1!Fee1) + Val(rst1!Fee2) + Val(rst1!Fee3) + Val(rst1!hndfee), 2)
   CONST3 = Round(CBalance(rst!AccountID), 2)
   AB5 = rst1!LoanType2
End If


Set rst6 = MyConn.Execute("Select * from tblLoanInt where Acctno = '" & rst!AccountID & "' and RefNo = '" & rst!RefNo & "'")
If rst6.BOF Then
Else
If RepMETHOD = "Daily" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + Val(rst6!PERIOD)
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Days"
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Weekly" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + (7 * Val(rst6!PERIOD))
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Weeks"
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Monthly" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + (30 * Val(rst6!PERIOD))
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Months"
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Semi - Monthly" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + (15 * Val(rst6!PERIOD))
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Semi-Months"
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Quarterly" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + (90 * Val(rst6!PERIOD))
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Quarters"
ElseIf RepMETHOD = "Bi - Annually" Then
   ExpDate = rst6!trndate + (180 * Val(rst6!PERIOD))
   A6 = Val(rst6!PERIOD) & " Bi-Annual"
End If

   A7 = Round(Val(rst6!Uint), 2)
End If

CONST4 = "PERFORMING"


AB1 = ""
AB2 = ""
AB3 = ""
AB4 = ""

Set rst6 = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblCustomersTable1 where acctno = '" & rst!acctno & "'")
If rst6.BOF Then
Else
CustBal1 = Round(Val(rst6!Balance), 2)
CustBlock = rst6!Blocked
AB1 = rst6!AcctD
AB2 = rst6!AcctO
AB3 = rst6!Ccode
AB4 = BranchName(rst6!Ccode)
end if



BAL1 = Val(CustBal1), 2)

CD3 = "0.01"
A3 = Val(rst6!Balance2)
CD4 = Round(Val(CD3) * Val(A3), 2)

Sno = Val(Sno) + 1


MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!AccountID & "','" & Replace(rst!CustomerName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & 

"','" & Replace(AccountOff(rst!AccountID), "'", "''") & "','" & Val(rst1!LOAN) & "','" & Val(rst!LBalance) & "','" & Val(rst1!INTEREST) & "','" & Val(A7) & "','" & A6 & 

"','" & Replace(rst1!Purpose, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst1!Colateral, "'", "''") & "','" & rst!RefNo & "','" & rst6!trndate & "','" & ExpDate & "','" & rst1!

LoanType2 & "','" & CONST4 & "','" & Val(rst!LBalance) & "','0','0','0','0','0','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) & "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" & CONST4 & "','" & AB1 & 

"','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")

BADA2:
PBar.Value = PBar.Value + 1
rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If

PBar.Value = Val(rstCount!CNT) + 1




' PART THREE - OVERDRAFT

Set rstCount = MyConn.Execute("Select count(*) as CNT from tblOverdraftTable1")
Set rst = MyConn.Execute("Select * from tblOverdraftTable1 order by acctno ")
If rst.BOF Then
Else
PBar.Max = Val(rstCount!CNT) + 1
PBar.Value = 0
Do Until rst.EOF

   CONST = Val(rst!Operiod)
   CONST2 = Val(rst!OAmt)

    If Val(A2) = 1 Then
    A6 = Val(rst!Operiod) & " Day"
    Else
    A6 = Val(rst!Operiod) & " Days"
    End If


CONST4 = "PERFORMING ADVANCES"

CD3 = "0.01"
A3 = Val(rst!OAmt)
CD4 = Round(Val(CD3) * Val(A3), 2)


AB1 = ""
AB2 = ""
AB3 = ""
AB4 = ""
AB5 = ""
Set rst6 = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblCustomersTable1 where acctno = '" & rst!acctno & "'")
If rst6.BOF Then
Else
CustBal1 = Round(Val(rst6!Balance), 2)
CustBlock = rst6!Blocked
AB1 = rst6!AcctD
AB2 = rst6!AcctO
AB3 = rst6!Ccode
AB4 = BranchName(rst6!Ccode)
AB5 = "OVERDRAFT"
end if


If Val(CustBal1) >= 0 Then
   GoTo BADA3
End If

If Val(CustBal1) * -1 >= Val(rst!OBal) Then
   A7 = Val(rst!OBal)
Else
   A7 = Val(CustBal1) * -1
End If

Sno = Val(Sno) + 1


MyConn.Execute ("Insert into tblLoanTable1Temp3 values ('" & rst!acctno & "','" & Replace(rst!ACCTName, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(rst!Accttype, "'", "''") & "','" & 

Replace(AccountOff(rst!acctno), "'", "''") & "','" & Val(rst!OBal) & "','" & Val(A7) & "','0','0','" & A6 & "','" & rst!Purpose & "','" & rst!Colateral & "','" & rst!

RefNo & "','" & rst!Startdate & "','" & rst!Enddate.Value & "','OVERDRAFT','" & CONST4 & "','" & Val(rst!OAmt) & "','0','0','0','0','0','" & Val(CD4) & "','" & Val(BAL1) 

& "','" & dtDate1.Value & "','" & CONST4 & "','" & AB1 & "','" & AB2 & "','" & AB3 & "','" & AB4 & "','" & AB5 & "','" & PostUser & "','" & Val(Sno) & "')")

BADA3:
PBar.Value = PBar.Value + 1
rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If
```

Looking forward to some help here

Comment: Can you break the code and make it usable for multiple functions, Break in a way so that you can run multiple scripts to get different results?

Comment: We can't really debug this for you, it's a big dump of SQL with no database schema. Why don't you break it down into pieces. Run it in small pieces. See what takes a long time. This is a good process for all types of programming problems. Work on small pieces. Make them good. Then build something bigger out of them.

Comment: I don't know if this will save you much overhead, but it will save you a little. Where you have the `If CONST = whatever` with a bunch of `ElseIf` statements also for `CONST` you might use `Select` instead. That will evaluate `CONST` only once, whereas each `ElseIf` will re-evaluate it.

Comment: You tagged it as sql-server-2008 but the tables are named like Access. Is this an access database?

Comment: @Troy Turley, no, the database is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Ultimately I think you're going to need to rewrite those VB programs to make them more efficient. Your databases may need redesigned as well. But, you might try shrinking the database then updating the statistics. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database -- and --
https://sqlbak.com/blog/update-statistics-sql-server/

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you are constantly re-querying different tables across the common account id field, this is not how you interact with a relational database.  You need to craft your queries using JOINs to express the table relationships and so read from multiple tables at once in as fewest queries as possible.

Comment: If you don't want to do the work described by @AlexK.(ie, normalizing your queries and db schema), or if you don't understand what that is, at the very least ensure that you have appropriately defined indices and/or primary keys on the tables for the columns used in your select where clauses (acctno, accountid, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that I can think of...

1. You would probably see a performance improvement by changing at least the first Connection.Execute into Recordset.Open - ReadOnly ForwardOnly

Instead of:

```
Set rst = MyConn.Execute("select * from tblLoanTable1 where Acctno <> '' order by AcctNo")
```

Do This:

```
Dim strSQL as String 
strSQL = "select * from tblLoanTable1 where Acctno <> '' order by AcctNo"

Dim rst as new ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open strSQL, MyConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

2. Are you sure that you have proper indexing on tblLoanTable1 , tblOverdraftTable1 and tblCustomersTable1

Be sure to have an index on these columns:

tblLoanTable1 -- Acctno

tbloverdrafttable1 -- Acctno , expirydate

tblCustomersTable1 -- Acctno